# Asp.Net Core EF Core many to many relation update command

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I followed this link [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#other-relationship-patterns) to create many to many relationship. But, I do not know how to create and update Tag value to Post Object.
Any help would be appreciated.

Update, related code

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.PostId, t.TagId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Post)
            .WithMany(p => p.PostTags)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.PostId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Tag)
            .WithMany(t => t.PostTags)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.TagId);
    }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public List<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public string TagId { get; set; }

    public List<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }
}

public class PostTag
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }

    public string TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Update2: Code for Update record
With below code, it will create records in both three tables.

```
    var p = new Post { Content = "C1" };
    var t = new Tag { TagId = "T1" };
    var pt = new PostTag { Post = p, Tag = t };
    _context.PostTag.Add(pt);
    _context.SaveChanges();
```

But, with below code, it will insert new records in middle table PostTag instead of update the previous records.

```
    var t1 = new Tag { TagId = "T3" };
    var t2 = new Tag { TagId = "T4" };

    var p =_context.Posts.Find(1);
    p.PostTags = new List<PostTag>() {
        new PostTag{ Post=p, Tag=t1},
        new PostTag{ Post=p, Tag=t2}
    };
    _context.Posts.Update(p);
    _context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Share code of your model classes

Comment: It is the code from the link, I have updated my post.

Comment: Code works fine. What is the result are you expecting? Especially can you elaborate on "instead of update the previous records." What previous records are you updating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's create some sample data

```
var p = new Post { ... };
var t = new Tag { ... };
var pt = new PostTag { Post = p, Tag = t };
```

This is still in-memory so we have to add it to the context, starting with:

```
db.Posts.Add(p);
db.Tags.Add(t);
```

Note that at this stage neither `p` nor `t` has any knowledge of `pt`. There are two ways to insert the third entity into your database.

1) The easiest way is to add the `DbSet<PostTag>` property and then the line

```
db.PostTags.Add(pt);
```

2) Without that extra DbSet you will need to ensure the linking from the other 2 sides. You also need to set up the List properties:

```
p.PostTags = new List<PostTag> { pt };
t.PostTags = new List<PostTag> { pt };
```

EF will now fill out any missing link fields.

Comment: thanks, it seems I need to manually operate the middle table to insert relationship between Post and Tag, am I right? Is this simple way not available for asp.net core [Configure Many-to-Many relationship using DataAnnotation](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) which I just need to set Tag property for post? It seems not easy to update the Tags for Post.

Comment: I'm not sure if EF Core will do this but you'd have to start by changing the two `List<PostTag> PostTags` properties to `List<Post>` and `List<Tag>` respectively.

Comment: After check [link](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5965), it is not supported currently. Sadly. Is there any better way to use update and delete on related records?